# not putting a = in a for loop hanged my laptop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, inline

Hello I'm new to programming so please don't mind my silly questions. And please help me!

So, I was learning loops and started with for loop. I wanted to display :

1
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91

(10 getting added to 1)

So I was referring a youtube video and it suggested the following way :

```
<html>
  <title>I'm Learning</title>
</html>
<body>
  <script>
    for (var a = 1; a<=100;a = a+10){
        document.write(a + "<br>")
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Which worked.[image] But, when I removed `a =` from `for (var a = 1; a<=100;a = a+10)` I thought it should still work as the value of a will still get changed. But, the webpage kept loading and after a while my laptop hanged. This happened twice. The webpage did not even load! So can anyone please help me with this? Please explain me if possible that why this error occurred. Thank You.

I was  expecting that the output would not change.

Comment: `But, when I removed a = from for (var a = 1; a<=100;a = a+10) I thought it should still work as the value of a will still get changed.` Well you're wrong. `a+10` doesn't change `a`.

Comment: but in every for loop code if u wanna just do a++ , they dont add a =

Comment: `a++` changes `a`.

Comment: [Postfix increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#increment_and_decrement) adds 1 to the variable, if you want to shorten your code use `a += 10`.

Comment: It would be just easier and faster to refer documentation rather than spend time to write this question, so I’m confused

Comment: `a++` is the same as `a = a + 1` -- `a += 10` is the same as `a = a + 10`. Question closed

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also By a += 10 you need to assign the new value with the = aka the assign operator and it should still work :) you can't just blindly a + 10 unless you are doing it with an increment of 1 then you can do something like a++